# Python relation/communication between two or more threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm new in Python, so I need some help.

I created a server with

> SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer

but my question is: Is there any way to communicate between two thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can share a Queue http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html between the threads.

Answer (score 3):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) is an event-driven networking engine written in Python and licensed under the open source (MIT license). You can use it for between thread communication.